# How does programmers.stackexchange.com implement the custom font in its nav menu?

Tags: javascript, fonts, webfonts

[Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) implements the "Whiteboard" font on its top navigation menu.

The text is selectable and works in IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. It seems JS-based as there is a slight delay before the text changes to the custom font.

*PS: I've marked the first correct answer as the accepted answer.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They appear to be simply using [@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/@font-face). No JS is involved as far as I can see. In browsers that don't support @font-face a `sans-serif` font will be displayed instead.

Answer (score 2):

The white board font is implemented using @Font-Face attribute of CSS2. You can read a general discription of how to implement custom font on your own website from [here](http://www.css3.info/preview/web-fonts-with-font-face/)

Programmers SE implements the "Whiteboard" font is implemented by

```
@font-face {
  font-family:'WhiteboardRegular';
  src: url('img/house-webfont.eot');
}
```

You can check this by going into the all.css of the Programmers SE

Comment: Sorry have not checked tat but it should validate, since its part of CSS2.

Answer (score 0):

Use font-family in css and http://www.google.com/webfonts to load fonts on your page.

For example add this to html

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Seaweed+Script' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

and this in your css:

```
body {
    font-family: 'Seaweed Script', cursive;
}
```